# Curl: (6) cannot resolve host

Tags: php, sh

hello every time i run my shell script the outcome "curl:(6) Couldn't resolve host '(temp=35.4&lux=7&hum=23.8)' and then it print out the code in my php file which does the reviving data and put it a text file? do anyone know what is this problem?
In my shell Script

```
while true;
do sleep 2
/home/GPIO/led 1
temp="$(/home/Temp/getTemp)"
lux="$(/home/Light/getLux)"
hum="$(/home/Humid/getHumid)"
/usr/bin/curl "("'temp'=$tmp'&''lux'=$lux'&''hum'=$hum")"             http://192.168.4.3/api.php
```

in my api.php

```
<?php
    $recivedpostdata=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $datafile = 'data.txt';
    file_put_contents($datafile,$recivedpostdata);
    echo $recivedpostdata;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl --data "temp=...&lux=..." http://192.168.4.3/api.php`

Not sure what you've trying to achieve, but if you want to `POST` temp and so on as parameters, this should do. Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request.

Comment: hello i was try to get the temp from the senor itself and post it to data.txt. i try your code but it still say curl could't resolve host  'temp=34.0&lux2&hum=1.0'. thanks

Comment: When I execute `curl --data "temp=34.0&lux2&hum=1.0" http://www.google.com/nonexistingpage.php`, I receive the response from Google's server (`...<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>...`). So it works. If it doesn't for you, there's another error somewhere. What happens if you just copy&paste this `curl` line and execute it on the shell? You get the message that it couldn't resolve the host?

Comment: i excute that curl on my terminal and now i got an error saying curl: (3) <url> malformed what does that mean ?

Comment: ah it work alr i forget to put the curl --data part. thank you very much

Comment: Glad it worked; don't forget to accept this as an answer; easier to find for future users, reputation increase - benefits for everybody.